# Spring-batch + Integration DSL throwing Dispatcher not found exception after job is over

Tags: spring-integration, spring-batch

I have implemented Spring Batch + Spring Integration combination with DSL referring to following link

https://github.com/cppwfs/spring-batch/blob/1f7cada52aba95bcb23d06bc034b21fe1de0a7a5/spring-batch-docs/asciidoc/spring-batch-integration.adoc#launching-batch-jobs-through-messages

Here is the code.

```
@Bean
public IntegrationFlow integrationFlowUi(JobLaunchingGateway jobLaunchingGateway) {
    return IntegrationFlows.from(Files.inboundAdapter(new File(incomingDirUi)).
                    filter(new SimplePatternFileListFilter("*.csv")).
                    filter(new AcceptOnceFileListFilter<>()),
            c -> c.poller(Pollers.fixedRate(500).maxMessagesPerPoll(1))).
            channel("bridgeChannel").
            handle(fileMessageToJobRequest()).
            handle(jobLaunchingGateway).
            log(LoggingHandler.Level.WARN, "headers.id + ': ' + payload").
            get();
}
```

with Batch config as

```
@Bean
public Job fundingCardActivationJob() {
    return jobBuilderFactory.get("fundingCardActivationJob")
            .incrementer(new RunIdIncrementer())
            .flow(activationStep())
            .next(fileRenamingStep())
            .end()
            .build();
}
```

Job runs. But At the end it throws following exception.

```
2017-12-15 12:39:54.867  WARN 13723 --- [ask-scheduler-1] headers.id + ': ' + payload              : GenericMessage [payload=JobExecution: id=572, version=2, startTime=Fri Dec 15 12:39:52 PST 2017, endTime=Fri Dec 15 12:39:54 PST 2017, lastUpdated=Fri Dec 15 12:39:54 PST 2017, status=COMPLETED, exitStatus=exitCode=COMPLETED;exitDescription=, job=[JobInstance: id=348, version=0, Job=[fundingCardActivationJob]], jobParameters=[{input.file.name=/Users/sudhir/ui/fundactive_2748_4444444444444444_2017-11-17_12-12-20.018.csv}], headers={id=4dcafdd0-aaed-ff62-bed9-781db41dfdf2, timestamp=1513370394863}]
```

> 2017-12-15 12:39:54.900 ERROR 13723 --- [ask-scheduler-1] o.s.integration.handler.LoggingHandler   : org.springframework.messaging.MessageDeliveryException: Dispatcher has no subscribers for channel 'application.integrationFlowUi.channel#2'.; nested exception is org.springframework.integration.MessageDispatchingException: Dispatcher has no subscribers, failedMessage=GenericMessage [payload=JobExecution: id=572, version=2, startTime=Fri Dec 15 12:39:52 PST 2017, endTime=Fri Dec 15 12:39:54 PST 2017, lastUpdated=Fri Dec 15 12:39:54 PST 2017, status=COMPLETED, exitStatus=exitCode=COMPLETED;exitDescription=, job=[JobInstance: id=348, version=0, Job=[fundingCardActivationJob]], jobParameters=[{input.file.name=/Users/sudhir/ui/fundactive_2748_4444444444444444_2017-11-17_12-12-20.018.csv}], headers={id=4dcafdd0-aaed-ff62-bed9-781db41dfdf2, timestamp=1513370394863}], failedMessage=GenericMessage [payload=JobExecution: id=572, version=2, startTime=Fri Dec 15 12:39:52 PST 2017, endTime=Fri Dec 15 12:39:54 PST 2017, lastUpdated=Fri Dec 15 12:39:54 PST 2017, status=COMPLETED, exitStatus=exitCode=COMPLETED;exitDescription=, job=[JobInstance: id=348, version=0, Job=[fundingCardActivationJob]], jobParameters=[{input.file.name=/Users/sudhir/ui/fundactive_2748_4444444444444444_2017-11-17_12-12-20.018.csv}], headers={id=4dcafdd0-aaed-ff62-bed9-781db41dfdf2, timestamp=1513370394863}]
>       at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractSubscribableChannel.doSend(AbstractSubscribableChannel.java:93)
>       at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel.send(AbstractMessageChannel.java:425)
>       at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel.send(AbstractMessageChannel.java:375)
>       at org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSend(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:115)
>       at org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSend(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:45)
>       at org.springframework.messaging.core.AbstractMessageSendingTemplate.send(AbstractMessageSendingTemplate.java:105)
>       at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageProducingHandler.sendOutput(AbstractMessageProducingHandler.java:360)
>       at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageProducingHandler.produceOutput(AbstractMessageProducingHandler.java:271)
>       at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageProducingHandler.sendOutputs(AbstractMessageProducingHandler.java:188)
>       at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.handleMessageInternal(AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.java:115)
>       at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageHandler.handleMessage(AbstractMessageHandler.java:127)
>       at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.AbstractDispatcher.tryOptimizedDispatch(AbstractDispatcher.java:116)
>       at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.UnicastingDispatcher.doDispatch(UnicastingDispatcher.java:148)
>       at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.UnicastingDispatcher.dispatch(UnicastingDispatcher.java:121)
>       at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractSubscribableChannel.doSend(AbstractSubscribableChannel.java:89)
>       at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel.send(AbstractMessageChannel.java:425)
>       at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel.send(AbstractMessageChannel.java:375)
>       at org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSend(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:115)
>       at org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSend(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:45)
>       at org.springframework.messaging.core.AbstractMessageSendingTemplate.send(AbstractMessageSendingTemplate.java:105)
>       at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageProducingHandler.sendOutput(AbstractMessageProducingHandler.java:360)
>       at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageProducingHandler.produceOutput(AbstractMessageProducingHandler.java:271)
>       at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageProducingHandler.sendOutputs(AbstractMessageProducingHandler.java:188)
>       at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.handleMessageInternal(AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.java:115)
>       at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageHandler.handleMessage(AbstractMessageHandler.java:127)
>       at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.AbstractDispatcher.tryOptimizedDispatch(AbstractDispatcher.java:116)
>       at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.UnicastingDispatcher.doDispatch(UnicastingDispatcher.java:148)
>       at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.UnicastingDispatcher.dispatch(UnicastingDispatcher.java:121)
>       at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractSubscribableChannel.doSend(AbstractSubscribableChannel.java:89)
>       at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel.send(AbstractMessageChannel.java:425)
>       at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel.send(AbstractMessageChannel.java:375)
>       at org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSend(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:115)
>       at org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSend(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:45)
>       at org.springframework.messaging.core.AbstractMessageSendingTemplate.send(AbstractMessageSendingTemplate.java:105)
>       at org.springframework.integration.endpoint.SourcePollingChannelAdapter.handleMessage(SourcePollingChannelAdapter.java:210)
>       at org.springframework.integration.endpoint.AbstractPollingEndpoint.doPoll(AbstractPollingEndpoint.java:272)
>       at org.springframework.integration.endpoint.AbstractPollingEndpoint.access$000(AbstractPollingEndpoint.java:58)
>       at org.springframework.integration.endpoint.AbstractPollingEndpoint$1.call(AbstractPollingEndpoint.java:190)
>       at org.springframework.integration.endpoint.AbstractPollingEndpoint$1.call(AbstractPollingEndpoint.java:186)
>       at org.springframework.integration.endpoint.AbstractPollingEndpoint$Poller$1.run(AbstractPollingEndpoint.java:353)
>       at org.springframework.integration.util.ErrorHandlingTaskExecutor$1.run(ErrorHandlingTaskExecutor.java:55)
>       at org.springframework.core.task.SyncTaskExecutor.execute(SyncTaskExecutor.java:50)
>       at org.springframework.integration.util.ErrorHandlingTaskExecutor.execute(ErrorHandlingTaskExecutor.java:51)
>       at org.springframework.integration.endpoint.AbstractPollingEndpoint$Poller.run(AbstractPollingEndpoint.java:344)
>       at org.springframework.scheduling.support.DelegatingErrorHandlingRunnable.run(DelegatingErrorHandlingRunnable.java:54)
>       at org.springframework.scheduling.concurrent.ReschedulingRunnable.run(ReschedulingRunnable.java:81)
>       at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
>       at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:293)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
>       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
>   Caused by: org.springframework.integration.MessageDispatchingException: Dispatcher has no subscribers, failedMessage=GenericMessage [payload=JobExecution: id=572, version=2, startTime=Fri Dec 15 12:39:52 PST 2017, endTime=Fri Dec 15 12:39:54 PST 2017, lastUpdated=Fri Dec 15 12:39:54 PST 2017, status=COMPLETED, exitStatus=exitCode=COMPLETED;exitDescription=, job=[JobInstance: id=348, version=0, Job=[fundingCardActivationJob]], jobParameters=[{input.file.name=/Users/sudhir/ui/fundactive_2748_4444444444444444_2017-11-17_12-12-20.018.csv}], headers={id=4dcafdd0-aaed-ff62-bed9-781db41dfdf2, timestamp=1513370394863}]
>       at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.UnicastingDispatcher.doDispatch(UnicastingDispatcher.java:154)
>       at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.UnicastingDispatcher.dispatch(UnicastingDispatcher.java:121)
>       at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractSubscribableChannel.doSend(AbstractSubscribableChannel.java:89)
>       ... 52 more

I have no idea why the exception is being thrown when integration configuration seems complete.

Comment: Edit the question to add the full stack trace so we can see which channel it is.

Comment: Done. Added exception trail.

Answer (score 0):

Something is closing (or stopping) the application context before the `JobExecution` result is sent to the `.log()`.

Comment: Thanks Gary for the comment. Looks channel number in the integrationFlowUi indicates where it is failing. I removed .log statement because it was as is copied from the link provided by Spring developer. But it gives exception now Caused by: org.springframework.messaging.core.DestinationResolutionException: no output-channel or replyChannel header available . I have followed the article as is, so I am not really sure what can cause ApplicationContext to get closed

Comment: Right; a DEBUG log for `org.springframework` should show the context being stopped/closed. Just removing the `.log()` won't work since the gateway returns a reply, it needs to be sent somewhere. If you don't care about the result, use `.channel("nullChannel")` after the `.handle()`.

Comment: Thanks ! that worked. But I have weird problem. Even if the file is processed completely. When I stop the process and restart it. Even if there is no input file, spring-integration/spring-batch remembers the previous processed file and tries to process again. As if, SI/SB, has temporary memory/cache which is not cleared. Btw, this problem was there before this nullChannel fix as well, nothing related to this fix.

Comment: Are you removing or renaming the file after completion? If you don't, the `AcceptOnceFileListFilter` only prevents duplicates for the duration of the JVM - it keeps state in memory. Consider using a `FileSystemPersistentAcceptOnceFileListFilter` with a `MetadataStore` instead.

Comment: Yes, I am renaming the file! Looks like this MetaDataStore you mentioned here has nothing to do with Spring-batch metadata. The packages are SI packages. I do not want to use persistent database for SI metadata, can I use SimpleMetadataStore ?

Comment: There's no point in switching to a `SimpleMetadataStore` it, too, keeps its metadata in memory. You could use a `PropertiesPersistingMetadataStore` which stores data in a `.properties` file but it won't perform well if the metadata gets large. If you are renaming the file, I can't explain why it is being processed again; there is nothing cached in Integration or Batch. Again, DEBUG logs should help.

Comment: Thanks for immediate response ! I tried PropertiesPersistingMetadataStore , it is making entries into metadata-store.properties, But it is still throwing same error. Debug log does not look like it is giving any useful information. Can you please let me know where should I look ?

Comment: Post the debug log someplace like github gist, pastebin, etc.

Comment: Sure. Here it is https://gist.github.com/anonymous/475383033b22ba6f3bf814d1dd864f7b

Comment: here is remaining part https://gist.github.com/anonymous/88a368b230a053399c7449936ba855d4

Comment: I see nothing happing on the poller thread `2017-12-18 15:20:00.377 DEBUG 12815 --- [ask-scheduler-3] o.s.i.e.SourcePollingChannelAdapter      : Received no Message during the poll, returning 'false'`. The problem's occurring on the application's `main` thread: `2017-12-18 15:20:00.854 ERROR 12815 --- [           main] o.s.batch.core.step.AbstractStep         : Encountered an error executing step fundingCardActivationStep in job fundingCardActivationJob`